# Finding critical values for the Pearson correlation coefficient

Tags: r

I'd like to use R to find the critical values for the Pearson correlation coefficient.

This has proved difficult to find in search engines since the standard variable for the Pearson correlation coefficient is itself *r*. In turn, I'm finding a lot of *r* critical value tables (rather than how to find this by using the statistical package R).

I'm looking for a function that will provide output like the following:

[image]

I'm comfortable finding the correlation with:

```
cor(x,y)
```

However, I'd also like to find the critical values.

Is there a function I can use to enter *n* (or degrees of freedom) as well as alpha in order to find the critical value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general structure of hypothesis testing is kind of a mish-mash of two systems: Fisherian and Neyman-Pearson. Statisticians understand the differences but rarely does this get clearly presented in undergraduate stats classes. R was designed by and intended for statisticians as a toolbox, so they constructed a function named `cor.test` that will deliver a p-value (part of the Fisherian tradition) as well as a confidence interval for "r" (derived on the basis of the Neyman-Pearson formalism.) Fisher and Neyman had bitter disputes in their lifetime. The "critical value" terminology is part of the N-P testing strategy. It is equivalent to building a confidence interval and finding the particular statistic that reaches exactly a threshold value of 0.05 significance.

The code for constructing the inferential statistics in `cor.test` is available with:

```
 methods(cor.test)
 getAnywhere(cor.test.default)
 #  scroll down 
 method <- "Pearson's product-moment correlation"
 #-----partial code----
    r <- cor(x, y)
    df <- n - 2L
    ESTIMATE <- c(cor = r)
    PARAMETER <- c(df = df)
    STATISTIC <- c(t = sqrt(df) * r/sqrt(1 - r^2))
    p <- pt(STATISTIC, df)
   # ---- omitted some set up and error checking ----
   # this is the confidence interval  section------
        z <- atanh(r)
        sigma <- 1/sqrt(n - 3)
        cint <- switch(alternative, less = c(-Inf, z + sigma * 
            qnorm(conf.level)), greater = c(z - sigma * qnorm(conf.level), 
            Inf), two.sided = z + c(-1, 1) * sigma * qnorm((1 + 
            conf.level)/2))
        cint <- tanh(cint)
```

So now you know how R does it. Notice that there is no "critical value" mentioned. I suspect that your hope was to find some table where a tabulation of "r" and  "df" was laid out displaying the minimum "r" that would reach a significance of 0.05 for a given 'df'. Such a table could be built but that's not how this particular toolbox is constructed. You should now have the tools to build it yourself.

Answer (score 8):

The significance of a correlation coefficient, *r*, is determined by converting *r* to a *t*-statistic and then finding the significance of that *t*-value at the degrees of freedom that correspond to the sample size, *n*. So, you can use R to find the critical *t*-value and then convert that value back to a correlation coefficient to find the critical correlation coefficient.

```
critical.r <- function( n, alpha = .05 ) {
  df <- n - 2
  critical.t <- qt(alpha/2, df, lower.tail = F)
  critical.r <- sqrt( (critical.t^2) / ( (critical.t^2) + df ) )
  return(critical.r)
}
# Example usage: Critical correlation coefficient at sample size of n = 100
critical.r( 100 )
```

Comment: How would you change this awesome function to "spearman" method?

Answer (score 2):

I would do the same. But if you are using a Spearman correlation you need to convert *t* into *r* using a different formula.

just change the last line before the return in the function with this one:

```
critical.r <- sqrt(((critical.t^2) / (df)) + 1)
```